Did hexachordal theory influence the construction of melodic phrases in Renaissance music?
I'm currently reading Gauldin's Practical Approach to 16th Century Counterpoint, Greene's Principles and Practice of Modal Counterpoint, and Schubert's Modal Counterpoint: Renaissance style.
Of these texts, Gauldin's and Schubert's address hexachordal theory only as something of a footnote, and Greene not at all.
Something that is not at all clear is whether hexachordal theory and solmization influence the construction of melodies, or whether it is merely a tool for teaching and/or memorisation.
All I have to go off is:

It's obvious that 'mutating' between hexachords within a given phrase is possible.
Gauldin notes that the music is made unnecessarily difficult if mutations occur too frequently (he cites this as one possible reason why leaps of major 6ths are avoided); though this is just as suggestive of it being a performance concern as it is a compositional one.
The naming of the hexachords is suggestive of their affect (i.e. perhaps melodic motion confined to a particular hexachord was intended to have a particular affect?)

Could anyone with experience here offer advice? Did hexachordal theory specifically influence the construction of melodies in Renaissance (and earlier) music, or was it merely a tool for performers to teach/memorise them?
Many thanks for your time!

With regard to the naming, my understanding is that the note now known in English as B flat was thought to be softer than the one now known as B natural, so they were known as soft B and hard B, respectively, and each gave its adjective to the hexachord that contains it.  There's no difference in the whole step from G to A whether it's ut-re, re-mi, or sol-la, and I doubt that composers of the period thought there was, either.

Wow, what a question. My answer: impossible to answer. By what criteria could we differentiate between a "hexachordally influenced" melody and a "not hexachordally influenced melody"?

Yes, all Renaissance composers learned the system of hexachords and viewed them as a resource (though not necessarily a rule) in composition.
When you look at the theme of a point of imitation, you'll usually find that the notes, or at least the main notes, belong to one hexachord (sometimes with octave displacement). This allows for imitation at the fourth or fifth, the most common intervals, without cross-relations nor distortions of the melody. In non-imitative voices (countermelodies), composers were freer and might mutate among hexachords more freely to touch the notes needed to fill out the harmony. For instance:

In Josquin's mass Hercules dux Ferrariae, the Agnus Dei II is a canon where the soprano sings only the notes of the natural hexachord. The bass imitates it at the octave below, and the alto imitates the soprano at the fourth below, on the hard hexachord.
In Palestrina's motet "Dies sanctificatus," the soprano opens with a theme that runs through the hard hexachord. The alto imitates it a fifth below, on the natural hexachord, and the other parts take it up in turn, still on these same hexachords. Shortly after the bass enters, the soprano introduces a countermelody that spans the whole scale from E to E and is not intended to be imitated. Ditto for the points of imitation at "venite gentes" (hard in bass, then natural in bass), "descendit lux magna in terris" (hard in soprano, natural in bass), and "haec dies" (soft in alto, natural in soprano), and "exultemus" (hard only).

Marin Mersenne, to give a sense of the vast possibilities of composition, dared to write out all 6! = 720 permutations of the six notes of the hexachord in his Harmonie universelle (1637). By then, a good chunk of them had appeared in some composition somewhere.

Thanks Mirlan - I appreciate the examples!

@mb_altho note however that the cantus firmus of the Missa Hercules dux Ferrariae was generated through an algorithm that essentially guarantees that it would comprise only notes of one hexachord. The algorithm was to map the vowels of the phrase Hercules dux Ferrariae to solmization syllables: re, ut, re, ut, re, fa, mi, re, giving D, C, D, C, D, F, E, D in the natural hexachord. It's therefore not perhaps the best example of a Renaissance composer devising a melody on musical principles.

@phoog noted, with thanks! It's evident that there are some works like this that are special cases.

@Mirlan: I spent a half hour today looking over a random selection. I observed what you've described in perhaps 60% of what I reviewed, (particularly in Palestrina's, which all seemed to conform). However, quite a few (e.g. Josquin's 'Missa Pange Lingua', Lasso's 'Christus resurgens' & Byrd's 'I have been young') have imitative themes that don't fit within one or another hexachord, and require a mutation very quickly. There were quite a few more that didn't require a mutation in the initial phrase, but did immediately after. Does this reflect your understanding?

@mb_altho You raise some interesting examples. In "Christus resurgens," note that the important notes of the theme—the only ones imitated consistently—are D-A-D-C, which belong to the natural hexachord, allowing for octave displacement (and themes spanning an octave, even with octave leaps, are commonplace; e.g. Palestrina's "O quantus luctus"). Josquin's "Missa Pange Lingua" is an interesting case because the main notes E-F-E are imitated as A-B-A (but surely some choirs would have done A-B♭-A). Still, we're in the natural hexachord; the descent from C isn't imitated at all.

Of course, there are Renaissance composers who deliberately used non-hexachordal themes, e.g. Handl's "Mirabile mysterium" includes imitation of a chromatic scale.
